# How can I hide a div after x seconds in blazor?

Tags: c#, timer, blazor

I have a div with a message:

```
@if (alertMessageShow)
{
    <div class="alert alert-success" style="margin-left: 50px"> Your changes have been saved </div>
}

@code {
    bool alertMessageShow = false;
}
```

`alertMessageShow` will be set to `true` when a user edits something on the page.

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to make the alert message disappear after, for example, 5 seconds.

I've tried setting up a timer and then on elapsed set `alertmessageshow` to `false` but that didn't seem to work.

I kept getting an `InvalidOperationException`.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
void alertMessage()
    {
        alertMessageShow = true;

        Timer _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 5000;
        _timer.Elapsed += AlertTimerElapsed;

        _timer.Start();
        
    }

    private void AlertTimerElapsed(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        alertMessageShow = false;
    }
```

So as soon as the alertMessage function is called, it will set the variable to true, then create a new instance of timer for 5 seconds, then on elapsed, it will change it back to false.

Button

```
<RadzenButton Icon="add_circle_outline" style="margin-bottom: 10px" Text="Nani" Click="@alertMessage" />
```

Comment: Can you share the code for the timer solution you tried? It'd be good to see what you tried and the error to help you debug :)

Comment: Oh yes im so sorry !

Comment: How to you call the alertMessage function?

Comment: @viveknuna when user clicks on a button

Comment: @jacky please share the code

Comment: @viveknuna i have provided button code now

Comment: `InvalidOperationException` doesn't tell us much.  What was the exception _message_?

Comment: I have no idea about your exception since it might happen for other reasons, but have you tried calling StateHasChanged() after the alertMessageShow = false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet demonstrate how to display the modal div and how to hide it. Note that the usage of the Timer object is not necessary, and may be considered over skilled.

Copy and test:

```
@page "/"

@if (alertMessageShow)
{

    <div class="alert alert-success" style="margin-left: 50px">@message</div>
}

<button type="button" @onclick="Save">Save Update</button>
@code {
    private bool alertMessageShow = false;
    private string message;

    private async Task Save()
    {
        message = "Saving update...";
        alertMessageShow = true;

        // Simulate saving operation, say, to a database. In a real world application the duration of
        // the delay is determined by the operation itslef; in other words, you do not use the line below
        await Task.Delay(5000);     

        message = "Updates saved...";
        await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());  
      
        // Wait 3 seconds for the user to read the message, and then close the modal
        await Task.Delay(3000);
       

        alertMessageShow = false;


    }
}
```

Note: I'd advise you to use toast notification modal dialog for such operations. See how [chrissainty](https://github.com/Blazored/Toast)  do that...

Answer (score 3):

A Timer is not needed here (and a Timer would need to be Disposed)

```cs
async Task ButtonClick()
{
   alertMessageShow = true;

   // when the Button has to do something else, add the next lines
   await task.Delay(1);
   // do some (async) work here
   StateHasChanged();

   // make sure the alert shows for a bit
   await task.Delay(5000);    
   alertMessageShow = false;
}
```

Comment: Do you need the `StateHasChanged`? The rerender will occur after `task.Delay(1)` anyway.

Comment: It's part of the "when the Button has to do something else" part.  When that changes the UI you want to show that before the Delay(5000).

Answer (score 0):

show in 3 seconds and then hide automatically in pure css.. for future reference. Tooltip.razor

```cs
<style>
    .tooltip-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
        cursor: help;
    }

    .more-tool-tip-span {
        position: absolute;
        width: 120px;
        bottom: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -60px;
        background-color: #363636;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px 0;
        border-radius: 6px;
        z-index: 1;
        height: fit-content;
       
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity:0;
    }

    .tooltip-wrapper:hover .more-tool-tip-span {
         -webkit-animation: fadeIn 3s ease normal;
    }

    @@keyframes fadeIn {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        100% {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
</style>
@if (TooltipPosition == Position.Top)
{
    <style>
        .more-tool-tip-span::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -5px;
            border-width: 5px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
        }
    </style>
}
<div class="tooltip-wrapper">

    <span style="@postCss" class="more-tool-tip-span">@Text</span>
    @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Text { get; set; }
    Position pos = Position.Bottom;
    [Parameter]
    public Position TooltipPosition
    {
        get { return pos; }
        set
        {
            pos = value;
            switch (value)
            {
                case Position.Bottom:
                    postCss.Add(Cp.Top, "100%");
                    postCss.Add(Cp.Bottom, "0px");
                    break;
                case Position.Right:
                    postCss.Add(Cp.Top, "50%");
                    postCss.Add(Cp.Bottom, "50%");
                    postCss.Add(Cp.Left, "100%%");
                    break;
                case Position.Left:
                    postCss.Add(Cp.Top, "50%");
                    postCss.Add(Cp.Bottom, "50%");
                    postCss.Add(Cp.Left, "0px");
                    postCss.Add(Cp.Right, "5%");
                    postCss.Add(Cp.Margin_Right, "100%");
                    postCss.Add(Cp.Margin_Left, "auto");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    StylerCode.Css.Css postCss = new StylerCode.Css.Css();
    public enum Position
    {
        Top,
        Left,
        Bottom,
        Right,
    }
}
```